# Mathematical equation with mixed data types in java

Tags: java, equation, algebraic-data-types

I've been given a problem to calculate the number of years(nbYear) it would take for a population(p0) to rise or decrease to a certain number of people(p) if the population would increas/decrease by precentage(percent) and additional people(aug) a year.

```
public static int nbYear(int p0, double percent, int aug, int p) {
    int nbYear = 0;
    while(p0 < p){
      p0 = p0 + (p0 * percent) + aug;
      nbYear = nbYear + 1;
    } 
    return nbYear;
}
```

}

This code would be ok but I get a possible lossy conversion from double to int error. My question is how can you calculate a mathematical equation with mixed data types in (this case int and double) without any information loss?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign a `double` value to an `int` variable without explicitly handling the data loss. One way to do this is to explicitly use a narrowing cast to `int`, under the assumption that a population cannot increase by a part of a person:

```
p0 = p0 + (int)(p0 * percent) + aug;
// Here --^
```

Comment: Is there really not any other solution beacuse doing this would make of to much data loss thus making the result not accurate.

Comment: @CWilliams you could call `Math.round` instead of casting, but I don't think that would be more accurate. Consider a simple case - you begin with 2 people and have a 30% growth rate. 2 * 1.3 = 2.6. What should the population be at the second year? 2 or 3?

Comment: If you don't want data loss, perform all calculations with doubles. If you want to display as int, cast to int the result.

Comment: Ok I solved it thanks to your comment.
It was wrong before beacuse of my mistake I received percentege in % all I had to do is to put them into normal numbers so I used the code:
  dobule percent1 = percent / 100;
and with your line with (int) it worked